# Problem with changing the header background with page scroll

Tags: html, css

I am implementing a fixed transparent header which turns black when the page is scrolled more than 100 pixels.

Currently, in main.js I have a function:

```
// Header scroll class
   $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
     $('.header').addClass('header-scrolled');
    } else {
      $('.header').removeClass('header-scrolled');
    }
  });
```

in main.css I have:

```
/*-------
# Header
---------*/
#header {
  padding: 3px 0;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  z-index: 997;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.header-scrolled {
  background-color: black;
}
```

and the html page is formatted as follows:

```
<header id="header" id="home">
  <div class="container">
     <li class="row align-items-center justify-content-between d-flex">
       <div id="logo">
         <a href="home.html"><img width="160" height="160" src="{% static 
         'img/my_logo.png' %}" alt="" title="" /></a>
       </div>
       <nav id="nav-menu-container">
         <ul class="nav-menu">
           <li class="menu-active"><a href="#home">{% trans "Home" %}</a> 
           </li>
           <li class="menu-active"><a href="#contacts">{% trans "Contacts" 
           %}</a></li>
         </ul>
       </nav>
     </li>
   </div>
</header>
```

Currently, the header is fixed and transparent. Yet, when I scroll down, it doesn't turn black (although in the inspector it seems that the header-scrolled is being added).
I cannot seem to find any solution to the problem (none of the provided other suggestion of similar questions work)... Perhaps I am missing something?

Comment: You need to check your markup. I don't see an ending tag for `<li class="row align-items-center justify-content-between d-flex">`

Comment: You are missing how _CSS specificity_ works, so please go read up on that.

Comment: And how is this a django question exactly ? (tag removed)

Answer (score 1):

Hope it will help.

```
#header.header-scrolled {
  background-color: black;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have build a plain JavaScript solution. Hopefully you can use it.

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/main.css">
  <title>Scroll CSS</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='navigation'>Navigation</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>

  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### main.scss

(if you want i can also post the resulting css)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;

  transition: all 0.5s;

  &.scrolled {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
}

p {
  &:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  width: 50vw;
}
```

#### index.js

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
  const navBar = document.querySelector('#navigation')
  const { pageYOffset } = window;


  if (pageYOffset >= 100) {
    navBar.classList.add('scrolled');
  }

  if (pageYOffset < 100) {
    navBar.classList.remove('scrolled');
  }
})
```

Comment: I tried incorporating this in my case, but it still has no effect.
I ques that it really is CSS specificity connected (something is getting overwritten in my css files) because in the inspector when I hover over the scrolled heather it shows:
 #header.header-scrolled {
    box-shadow: none;
}
Clearly don't have the box-shadow element in what I have defined. In addition, the background color is missing.
When I add it manually there:

#header.header-scrolled {
    box-shadow: none;
    background-color: black;
}
 it works as it should/is expected.

Comment: When I have some time tonight I will try out this stuff with jQuerry.

Answer (score 0):

I will post the jQuery solution here as separate answer for better reading, please try the following code for your index.js

#### index.js

```
$(window).scroll(() => {
 if (this.pageYOffset >= 100) {
    $('#navigation').addClass('scrolled');
  }

  if (this.pageYOffset < 100) {
    $('#navigation').removeClass('scrolled');
  }
})
```

just for the sake of completion also the html & css

#### index.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style/main.css">
  <title>Scroll CSS</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id='navigation'>Navigation</div>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Fuga tempore obcaecati voluptas earum alias enim, inventore eaque minus possimus delectus maxime soluta provident veritatis totam aspernatur cupiditate explicabo numquam aperiam eum vel? Perferendis, culpa laudantium? Ut, esse voluptates animi aut, beatae error blanditiis nisi voluptas id illo, consequatur accusantium nihil.</p>

  <script src="./index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

#### main.scss

(if you want i can also post the resulting css)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

#navigation {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: transparent;
  text-align: center;

  transition: all 0.2s;

  &.scrolled {
    color: white;
    background: black;
  }
}

p {
  &:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-top: 100px;
  }
  width: 30vw;
}
```

Comment: The same. Nothing changes. It seems that the problem is with me somewhere. Nevertheless, I am voting your answer up, as I am confident that it usually works and others can use it.

Comment: Do you mean the whole code? I am using a bootstrap theme and the whole code is structured in multiple files most of which are more than 1000 lines...

Comment: oh okay. Then I think there is something wrong in the css.  

In which order do you load your css?

Comment: Order:

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/linearicons.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/font-awesome.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/magnific-popup.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/nice-select.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/animate.min.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/owl.carousel.css' %}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">

.header-scrolled is in main.css, loaded last.

Comment: did you try to track with the dev-tools of your browser, where the  

```css
 #header.header-scrolled {
box-shadow: none;
} 
```
style is coming from?

Comment: or just diable all .*css files and enable them one after another to find the causing .*css file

Comment: It must be in main.css ... I disabled all of the other css files and the problem stayed. After removing all 'box-shadow: none;' elements from the main.css file, the same thing remained. This is getting really mysterious for me.

Comment: hmmm okay, that`s strange. Maybe as a next step, disable all rules/selectors in your main.css and enable on after another.

Comment: Okay, I did that (disabling all selectors in main.css), nothing changed. So, it is not from the main.css file itself. More interestingly, when I disabled the header class, nothing changed as well. I think that now there is no doubt that it is a specificity of the way bootstrap works. There is a folder named "scss". In it there are various scss files (including files such as main.scss and _header.scss). Unfortunately, nothing that I do to those files makes a difference as well.